# Rails in production environment not working,but it's working in development environment

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, production

> An ActionView::Template::Error occurred in posts#index:
>
> couldn't find file 'jquery'
> (in /opt/ruby_apps/bookdate-website/app/assets/javascripts/cpanel_app.coffee:1)
> sprockets (2.1.3) lib/sprockets/context.rb:100:in `resolve'
>
> An ActionView::Template::Error occurred in topics#show:
>
> cannot load such file -- html/tokenizer
> actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/vendor/html-scanner/html/sanitizer.rb:18:in >`tokenize'

sometimes there is an exception thrown like the one mentioned above,but sometime it works
why?

my ruby environment is
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Rails 3.2.8

when i connect to the server, anything look like ok,but when i disconnect the ssh from the terminal, the website throw 500 expcetion,the log file print some error like my question

Comment: You could try saying `rake assets:precompile` on production server

Comment: yes，i do it before to restart the rails server

Answer (score 0):

Where does your jquery come from? 
In general you:
a) have 'gem 'jquery-rails'' in your Gemfile, so you need to run 'bundle install' and make sure it is there, or
b) you copy the files in your assets folder somewhere, or
c) you use a a CDN hosted jquery file

I use the gem because it is easier.

Comment: a) jquert is in my Gemfile, it's gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
b) my vendor folder can't find anything like query file
c) i close my CDN hosted,but this problem isn't fixed

when i connect to the server, anything look like ok,but when i disconnect the ssh from the terminal, the website throw 500 expcetion,the log file print some error like my question

Comment: I occasionally have some odd errors, and they are related to a dependency within another gem. Maybe try to run a 'bundle outdated' to see which gems are outdated, and then a 'gem update'.

Comment: the problem is fixed! I reinstall my ruby runtime env with mulit user，look like nice!